# HTTP Connection lost when switching network interface on Android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working on an Ionic 2 application. My use case is quite simple, I display a page, and I use the angular2's Http service to retrieve a string on a remote API, and I display this string on my page. Every seconds, I did the same "GET" request, and I display this string.

If I start my application with WiFi activated and connected to a network, every things works fine. Then when I disable WiFi, I except my HTTP Packets to be sent through mobile network, but my HTTP request never get out of my phone (I check in my backends logs, and I can't see any trace of them).

Of course, this problem doesn't occurs with my development phone (on Android 5.x), but only on my customer's phone (on Android 4.4)... I guess that the old android version can't switch the network interface of an already opened TCP connection.

Does some one have already experienced this kind of problem ? And is there some solutions I can develop in my app ?

Comment: Is it possible to debug the device of your customer and look for possible error logs? You could debug it using logcat or chrome inspection.

Comment: For now I can't... But my customer will send me a phone on which I hope I will be able to re produce my problem (and so trace it with debug tools).